# istio JWT authentication for single service behind ingress gateway

Tags: kubernetes, jwt, istio

I have 2 services running on AKS (v1.16.13) and deployed the following istio (v1.7.3) configuration. First one is a UI where I invoke the OIDC flow and get JWT token, second one is a backend service which should require a valid JWT token.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: myapp-gateway
  namespace: "istio-system"
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - hosts:
    - myapp.com
    port:
      name: http-myapp
      number: 80
      protocol: HTTP
    tls:
      httpsRedirect: true
  - hosts:
    - myapp.com
    port:
      name: https-myapp
      number: 443
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      credentialName: myapp-credential
      mode: SIMPLE
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: myapp
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  gateways:
  - istio-system/myapp-gateway
  hosts:
  - myapp.com
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /ui
    route:
    - destination:
        host: myapp-ui.myapp.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 4200
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /backend/
    rewrite:
      uri: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: myapp-service-backend.myapp.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8080
---
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: RequestAuthentication
metadata:
  name: myapp-jwt-backend
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  jwtRules:
  - issuer: https://oktapreview.com
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp-service-backend
```

With that config I would expect to get 401 if I invoke **myapp.com/backend** but that's not the case. Request authentication doesn't kick in.

After some further research (https://discuss.istio.io/t/cannot-use-jwt-policy-with-an-externalname-virtualservice-target/2794/3), I found out that I can't apply RequestAuthentication on a VirtualService but only on a Gateway which is quite odd to me but ok. I've changed the RequestAuthentication to the following but still nothing has changed after invoking backend:

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: RequestAuthentication
metadata:
  name: myapp-jwt-backend
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  jwtRules:
  - issuer: https://oktapreview.com
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      istio: myapp-gateway
```

Do you have any idea how can I setup istio for my use case? Assuming the RequestAuthentication would work on a gateway, do I need 2 gateway? 1 for UI and the second for backend? Seems like an overkill.

Comment: You can apply requestauth to services in istio service mesh(Gateway auth not mandatory). If the incoming request contain invalid token, error occurs. If no auth token present, It will by default pass the request to backend.To change that behaviour, Apply a AuthorizationPolicy also.

Comment: thanks a lot. My bad, I should have gone through the documentation more in detail: https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authorization/authz-jwt/. It works now after adding the AuthorizationPolicy. Do you want to post an answer to get the reward?

Comment: I am glad it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the sachin's comment and going again through the documentation made me realized that I need AuthorizationPolicy on top of RequestAuthentication:

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:    
  name: myapp-require-jwt-backend
spec:
  action: ALLOW
  rules:
  - from:
    - source:
        requestPrincipals:
        - https://xxx/*
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp-service-backend
```

The request authentication is only making sure that when a JWT token is provided, it has to be a valid one. If there is no token, it will just pass through the request.